# Invalid ALTER TABLE option in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with oracle SQL.

My code:

```
alter table kontraktai add constraint kontraktai_siuntejai_fk 
  foreign key (SIUNTEJAI_SIUNT_TEL_NR) REFERENCES siuntejai (SIUNT_TEL_NR) 
  on delete cascade;
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table "kontraktai" add constraint kontraktai_siuntejai_fk foreign key (SIUNTEJAI_SIUNT_TEL_NR)
REFERENCES siuntejai SIUNT_TEL_NR on delete cascade
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That is: the column name must be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: After that same error

Comment: @Deima With the correction proposed in the comments, your constraint works perfectly fine (tested on 11g XE).

Comment: But on 12c is problem.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in 12c - do you get the same error or a different one?